# What should a LiPo's voltage be at full charge?

Tags: lipo-batteries, batteries, charging, voltage

How can I determine what the voltage of a LiPo should be when at full charge? Specifically, what should the voltage at full charge for a 2200mAh 20c 3-cell LiPo be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage of a LiPo battery at full charge can be calculated with the simple understanding that each cell in the battery should reach a peak voltage of 4.2V after charging.
Using this, we can make the simple formula:
$$
Voltage\ _{total} = 4.2V\ ⋅\ (number\ of\ cells)
$$

For your specific battery, the 3 cells means it would be 4.2 x 3 = **12.6V at full charge**